# Remove ethanol from gasoline by mixing it with water?

Tags: purification, fuel

I have read on forums that ethanol can be removed from commercial gasoline by mixing it with water, then draining water from the bottom to remove the water-ethanol solution (for example, with a separatory funnel).

Does this really work? I would assume the ethanol is homogenized with the gasoline somehow, so would that interfere with it binding to the water?

Comment: The "homogenization" will cause a percentage of the ethanol to remain in the gasoline, but the rest will migrate to the water phase. You can repeat the extraction (separation) multiple times to reduce this percentage remaining. I don't know anything about what the resulting solutions will be usable for though.

Comment: Yes, it would work, but would not be very useful: the ethanol would be very dilute, and some water droplets would remain in the gasoline, making it a problematic engine fuel.

Comment: Please don't just create tags to summarise your question. Tags should be used to categorise the questions. There will not be enough questions (probably ever) to sustain an ethanol tag.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン There are hundreds of questions dealing directly with ethanol and have "ethanol" in their title. Maybe instead of deleting my tag, you could have tagged the 100 or so major questions dealing with ethanol with my tag.

Comment: Yes I could have done that, but this would have undermined the process in which we create and use tags. Just because ethanol is a very common chemical, it doesn't mean that the uses are similar enough to group them apart from what is already accomplished by an ordinary search. Tags should be applied to things that cannot be searched easily.